# Invoiceninja loading invoices is extremely slow

Tags: ubuntu, invoice, invoice-ninja

I'm self-hosting an instance of Invoiceninja on Ubuntu 16.04 using Nginx and mysql

I currently only have about 1400 clients, 1700 invoices and 13k products. however loading invoices takes roughly 5-15 seconds per invoice. This doesn't seem like a lot of data to be slowing down so much.

I've added query caching in mysql but that has not alleviated any performance issues.

I've also tried to identify what exactly is holding up the load times using chrome's dev tools but I can't decipher what's causing the loading issues.

I tried posting this to the invoiceninja forums but for some reason I'm unable to create a new post.

Where should I be looking in order to identify what is holding up loading invoices?

Comment: What version of IN do you use? Does it only happen when loading invoices? Do you use docker?

Comment: currently using v4.5.17. Not using docker. And, yes, it only happens when loading invoices, no matter how many line items have been added to it.

Comment: I assume you run on PHP 7 and this problem is not totally new, so it was already slow with any earlier version of IN?

Comment: Yes, php7, and correct, this is not new. I'm assuming mysql query caching is not optimized properly? what would optimal setting be for caching?

Comment: Hmm.. that sounds strange. Would you mind joining the [Slack space](http://slack.invoiceninja.com/)? On the #develop channel you can reach the developers to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely related to the amount of products. Please use the new v5 which works hopefully more performant. 
Currently v5 is in alpha state, the official release is roughly in one month.

Check the [Github account](https://github.com/invoiceninja/invoiceninja) or the [forum](https://www.invoiceninja.com/forums/topic/the-new-invoice-ninja-alpha/) how to get the v5 up and running.